# Searching through more than one column in a query

Tags: sql, coldfusion, group-by

I'm currently working on a search function where users can search for gigs either by the name of the band who are hosting the gig, or the location of the gig itself. The issue I am having is for the location part of the search, I want to search through the town, county AND country fields I have stored so that say if a gigs location is "Leeds, Yorkshire, England" and the user searched for "Eng" it would match because it found it in the country field. Same would apply if they searched for "eds" because of the match in Leeds.

I know this can be achieved by using the Group By method within the query, however, I was looking for advice on best practices and exactly how to apply it as I have not used Group By before.

Here is the incorrect query I started with:

```
<cfquery datasource="#datasource#" name="findgigs">
    Select artist_id, gig_id, gig_artistid, gig_town, gig_county, gig_country
    From artists, gigs
    Where artist_id = gig_artistid
    <cfif IsDefined("URL.search")>
        And gig_town LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#%>
        Or gig_county LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#%>
        Or gig_country LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#%>
    </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

As I discovered after running the query (should of known before hand) it returns many duplicates. However, looking at that query you can see what I am trying to obtain it is just done in completely the wrong way. Any knowledge or advice on how to improve this would be appreciated.

Comment: "I was looking for advice on best practices" Don't use `select *` :)

Comment: Good point, ill edit that now.

Comment: What if you simply did a select distinct?

Comment: What would that do in the occurrence that there are matching countries found. Would this eliminate the matching records down to 1?

Comment: using distinct in this case would be moot because of the id fields making every record unique.

Comment: Best practice in my view would be to do this in solr rather than in mysql. A "Like '%xx%'" query such as this is not going to be very well optimized when you have a lot of data to deal with. Solr can handle queries like this brilliantly and then some.

Comment: I only have MySQL to use so this isn't really an alternative.

Comment: If you have ColdFusion, you have SOLR built in with super easy setup and use. If this application is just for fun or will only have a couple thousand rows of data, you are fine. If it would grow to tens of thousands, you will definitely see this become a problem.

Comment: We aren't sure as of yet how large it will grow, however I'm sure the lead designer will have that covered should the issue begin to arise. Thanks for the heads up though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your WHERE clause does not contain any grouping around your ORs.  This is causing the initial criteria to be ignored when checking for county or country.  Since you are using ANSI 89 syntax to handle your join (not specifying INNER JOIN), this will break your join.

There are a few ways to fix this.  If you wanted to continue using ANSI 89:

```
<cfquery datasource="#datasource#" name="findgigs">
    Select artist_id, gig_id, gig_artistid, gig_town, gig_county, gig_country
    From artists, gigs
    Where artist_id = gig_artistid
    <cfif IsDefined("URL.search")>
        And (gig_town LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#%">
        Or gig_county LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#%">
        Or gig_country LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#%">)
    </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

As you can see, all I did there is add a "(" After the "And" and a ")" after the last cfparam.  This will group those criteria together so the artist_id criteria is used against all three (preventing the extra results).

If you wanted to change the SQL to explicitly define your join (ANSI 92):

```
<cfquery datasource="#datasource#" name="findgigs">
    Select artist_id, gig_id, gig_artistid, gig_town, gig_county, gig_country
    From artists
    Inner Join gigs ON artist_id = gig_artistid
    <cfif IsDefined("URL.search")>
        Where gig_town LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#%">
        Or gig_county LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#%">
        Or gig_country LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#%">
    </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you very much, I should start broadening my SQL knowledge and probably use INNER JOIN more, i'm guessing inner join is a more efficient way of running a query?

Comment: No, it does the exact same thing, just with [ANSI-92](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-92) syntax (preferred) instead of ANSI-89 (outdated). The change in join style is not what fixed the problem. As Mike mentioned, you should always use parenthesis when mixing `AND` and `OR` operators to let the database know how you want the expressions evaluated. Otherwise, the database uses [its own precedence rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387132.aspx) and the results are usually not what you intended.

Answer (score 3):

```
<cfquery datasource="#datasource#" name="findgigs">
    SELECT  artist_id
    FROM    artists
    WHERE   artist_id IN 
      (    

           SELECT  gig_artistid 
           FROM    gigs 
           WHERE   1 = 0 
           <cfif structKeyExists(url,'search')>
             OR  gig_town LIKE  <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#">
             OR  gig_county LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#">
             OR  gig_country LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#">
         </cfif>
      )
</cfquery>
```

1. If you're worried about duplicated values, this sub query would help remedy that without grouping.
2. Added cfqueryparam in as a best practice to help against sql injections

The logic for the query is "show nothing to start" and then if your search is defined, the OR will kick in allowing the results to be shown.

Option #2

```
<cfquery datasource="#datasource#" name="findgigs">
    SELECT artist_id
    FROM   artists
   <cfif structKeyExists(url,'search')>
    WHERE  artist_id IN 
        ( 
           SELECT  gig_artistid 
           FROM    gigs
           WHERE   gig_town LIKE  <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#">
           OR      gig_county LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#">
           OR      gig_country LIKE <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="%#URL.search#">
       )
   </cfif>
</cfquery>
```

Starts by showing all.  If a search criteria is added it will start filtering out the results to include your search criteria.

Comment: I use cfqueryparam, just forgot to include on my code above. Shall edit now. And the way my query works is that if search isn't defined it returns all the records stored almost acting as a "list all" option.

Comment: ok, easy enough.  change 1=0 to 1=1.  THat will show all.  You may also want to consider the "or" to be "and".  1=1 will always show all records, even with the criteria applied to it.  If you change the first or right inside the cfif, to an and, that would do it... I will update my code to show a 2nd option.

Comment: Cheers, very helpful. I'll trial this now to see if either works for me.

Comment: For option #2, it is more efficient to just skip the entire subquery when the search parameter is not defined. ie `<cfif structKeyExists(URL, 'search')>
      WHERE EXISTS (
           ... run subquery ...
      )
</cfif>`